# How to uninstall Button Savior (non root) from Samsung Galaxy Note 4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-4, device-administrator

I asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667418/how-to-uninstall-button-savior-non-root-from-samsung-galaxy-note-4) and somebody suggested to me that I should asked here.

A friend of mine installed an app called Button Savior (non root) from google play and then decided to uninstall it for whatever reason, but he was not able to uninstall it from his phone, he then asked me to help him to uninstall it from his phone. I searched in google for how to do it, and I found this [link](https://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/735799-i-installed-app-named-button-savior-how-uninstal.html).

On this link it was suggested that I first should remove the app from the device administrators list (settings - security - device administrators) and then and uninstall it and if this fails then I should reboot the phone into safe mode and repeat the process. I tried both methods but when I try to remove the app from the device administrators list the setting crash and I got an error message "unfortunately setting has stopped working".

Any suggestions to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying to uninstall via adb. You'll need the following if you don't already:

- [ADB](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/)
- [Enable Developer options](https://www.greenbot.com/article/2457986/android/how-to-enable-developer-options-on-your-android-phone-or-tablet.html)

  After that, proceed as follows:

  1. Find the package name of the application on your phone that you want to uninstall. The easiest way is to use Package Name Viewer, or in your `Settings` under `Applications`.
  2. Enable `Debugging mode` through `Settings -> System -> Developer options -> USB debugging`
  3. Connect your phone to your PC
  4. Right click on an empty area in the Fastboot folder while holding the shift key, and click on “Open Command Window Here”.
  5. Now in command window type the following command: `adb uninstall packagename` where packagename is the name you found earlier (usually looks like `com.packagename.anotherthing`)
  6. As soon as you hit the Enter key, it will uninstall the App and show you `Success` in the command window.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way. Go to Play Store and search for the app. When the app is found, you will have two options - open or uninstall..